# How to create a database to access files using both R and Python?

Tags: python, r, database, shiny

I have almost zero knowledge of databases so please bear with me.

## Workflow

The following figure illustrates what I want to achieve:

[image]

1. We perform driving experiments in a driving simulator in our lab. The simulator saves the results in a 'DAQ' (Data Acquisition) file. Everyday about 8 files are expected to be generated. Each file is expected to have atleast million rows and about 250 columns.
2. I want to store these data files in a database. I don't know how to do that and what to use. So far my search revealed SQL, MySQL, NoSQL, MS Access, Hadoop, etc. but I still can't figure out how to simply store my files in a database and which one of the mentioned systems will be better in this case.
3. DAQ files can't be directly analysed so a Python library 'Undaq Tools' can convert DAQ to HDF5 format which can be analysed in Python as well as R. I am familiar with this step. I want to access the stored data from the database and convert all files to HDF5 using Python and then save them in the Database again, keeping the original DAQ files.
4. Finally I want to access the HDF5 data files to create a Shiny dashboard in R.

My main questions are: What type of database is useful in this case? Are there any tutorials that can help me learn storing and accessing the database in this case? Please help. I have tried searching all I could before posting this question but still have no clue how to begin.

Comment: This is likely to generate a number of opinion based answers and may be too subjective for Stack Overflow. For instance some will consider a million or two rows as big data while others are used to using relational databases for anything under 20 to 30 million rows. Beyond that your asking for recommendations for how to learn database administration is covered pretty well on [dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=tutorials&s=cfe16612-dbf1-40a2-9b48-8ccc72a02353)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So far my search revealed SQL, MySQL, NoSQL, MS Access, Hadoop, etc.
>   but I still can't figure out how to simply store my files in a
>   database and which one of the mentioned systems will be better in this
>   case.

SQL is a language, MySQL is a free relational database, MS Access is a relational database part of the MSOffice Suite, NoSQL is a non relational database often used for big data, and Hadoop is used for distributed processing. There are many, many more to a list of types of databases.

If you want free and easy, maybe start with MySQL. It usually provides the PHPMyAdmin Interface that may be easier for you to see the structure versus just SQL. You will seriously want to spend some time looking at how databases are structured and how to normalize data. It's not a server filesystem, so you do not simply upload files into it. It performs best when you can normalize the data and store them in relations. Then if you manipulate this data and want to update it in the database, you will need a strategy for that too. Most of the time is not spent in SQL or figuring out how to get the data into the database, but on how to normalize the data and build a schema.

There are APIs available for you to connect from within your Python programs and R programs.

To answer your question about resources:

What is database normalization?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

SQL:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/
  (note, SQL syntax can slightly vary depending on the database)

MySQL Community Server download (free version): http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

MySQL docs:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Python MySQL API:  https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1

R MySQL API:  https://github.com/rstats-db/rmysql

There are many APIs, these aren't the only ones, I just found those as top results from google.

Comment: Thanks. But when I search about MySQL I get tutorials on SQL language, some kind of SQL sever, etc. What I still don't know is how my files could be stored in the database. I know that I need to learn SQL syntax to access the files but that is the second step.

Comment: @umairdurrani SQL is the language for relational databases, SQL Server is a microsoft database. You should know SQL to set up the database as well. The database is empty until you create tables/relations. Like I mentioned, the best approach is to model your data by normalizing it and creating a schema of how you will store it. Then you make the database, then put data in it. I added a link to resources, including MySQL.

Comment: @umairdurrani I am also curious why you need a database for this if you want to preserve the file types. With your current approach, it would be better to do your data conversion in a staging area before putting in the database. The database is a way to store the data in a normalized structure, which will make working with it a lot easier in some cases and you can read the data by tuple, specific relationships, etc.  in your programs instead of having to output the entire dataset(file) at a time.